# PHP connect to MariaDB, Multiple Instances

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

I have a synology box and just upgraded MariaDB 5 to MariaDB 10.
The webpage I host there works but a PHP script updating data in the MariaDB database now fails

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'joomla_d'

In the phpMyAdmin I can choose to connect to MariaDB 5 where the DB does not exist and MariaDB 10 where it exists. How can I make this choice in my script?

Here is the PDO line that worke fine with the old DB:

```
$DB_Conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=$DB_Name", $DB_User, $DB_Pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```

Thank you for your help
Regards
Laurent

Comment: Is 10 running on a different port?

Comment: I tried to check, but I don't see this in phpMyAdmin!How to check...

Comment: Do you have a configuration file you set up 10 with? Maybe run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';`, not sure if that works in maria though.

Comment: Yes, they use port 3307 insted of 3306. I changed this in the statement and still get the same error

Comment: And `SHOW DATABASES;` shows that db?

Comment: is, it does show "joomla_d"

Answer (score 0):

I replaced "localhost" by "127.0.0.1" an it works now, still while keeping the new port address in the connection string.

Perhaps someone can confirm this!

Thank you to all contributing!
Cheers 
Laurent

Comment: localhost will cause mysql API to connect through UNIX socket, while IP address makes it connect throught TCP

Comment: OK.. So that's why it makes sense to use the IP address even if we are on localhost!